# Very Basic Java Game Networking?

Tags: java, networking, multiplayer

Our school project is to build a multiplayer game. We have the game finished, a rip-off of light bikes (Tron) that is already two players. How would I modify it so that it would work between two computers? I've done a little research on `UDPClient` and `UDPServer`. Would I need 3 computers to get this to work? 1 server and 2 clients?

Comment: Dig into the topic of "peer-to-peer" networking or gaming.  Often, one of the two game clients would function as the "server", the other would connect to it, and then they'd play.  It's downside is that it's extremely hackable.